# Equation of a tangent line to a lemniscate

Tags: implicit-differentiation, tangent-line

> Find the equation of the tangent line to $$(x^2 + y^2)^3 = x^2 - y^2$$
>   at the point $(0, 0)$.

This is the problem I'm encountering: after taking the implicit derivative, I plug $(0, 0)$ in. Everything cancels out and I get the equation $0 = 0$.

Comment: I think you should plot this curve so you (and we) have some idea what you are talking about. For one thing, I wonder about the cubic power if you say it's a lemniscate.

Comment: Must all lemniscates have a quadratic power instead of a cubic power?

Comment: No, you're absolutely correct; it can have any power, including fractional powers. I was throw off by something else. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is a figure 8
which crosses the origin
and has two possible tangents.

From
$(x^2 + y^2)^3 = x^2 - y^2
$,
I get

$\begin{array}\\
2x-2yy'
&=3(2x+2yy')(x^2+y^2)^2\\
&=3(2x(x^2+y^2)^2+2yy'(x^2+y^2)^2)\\
\text{or}\\
2yy'(3(x^2+y^2)^2+1)
&=2x(1-3(x^2+y^2)^2)\\
\text{or}\\
yy'(3(x^2+y^2)^2+1)
&=x(1-3(x^2+y^2)^2)\\
\end{array}
$

At the origin,
and this is the key observation,
$y \approx xy'
$
so this becomes
$xy'^2(3(x^2+y^2)^2+1)
\approx x(1-3(x^2+y^2)^2)
$
or
$y'^2(3(x^2+y^2)^2+1)
\approx (1-3(x^2+y^2)^2)
$.

Setting
$x = y = 0$,
$y'^2
\approx 1
$
so
$y' = \pm 1$.

---

Here is a simpler way
(which I thought of
after submitting the above).

Let
$y = ax$ at the origin.

From
$(x^2 + y^2)^3 = x^2 - y^2
$
we get
$(x^2 + a^2x^2)^3 = x^2 - a^2x^2
$
or
$x^6(1 + a^2)^3 = x^2(1 - a^2)
$
or
$x^4(1 + a^2)^3 = (1 - a^2)
$.

Setting
$x=0$,
$1-a^2 = 0$
or
$a = \pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in polar form, the curve is $$r^6=r^2\cos2\theta$$ and $r\neq0$

As $r\rightarrow 0$, $\cos 2\theta\rightarrow 0$ so the tangents at the origin are $\theta=\pm\frac{\pi}{4}$ i.e. $$y=\pm x$$